# Docker for Windows bind volume mounts empty volume in Windows 10

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I am trying to mount a host folder into the container volume, but the volume is empty.

OS Version:

```
Edition: Windows 10 Enterprise
Version: 1709
OS Build: 16299.1087
```

Docker Version:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           18.09.1
API version:       1.39
Go version:        go1.10.6
Git commit:        4c52b90
Built:             Wed Jan  9 19:34:26 2019
OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
Engine:
Version:          18.09.1
API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
Go version:       go1.10.6
Git commit:       4c52b90
Built:            Wed Jan  9 19:41:49 2019
OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
Experimental:     false
```

Following is what I am doing.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.13
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
#COPY /build/default . -- for server deployment
COPY /bower_components .
COPY /src .
COPY index.html .
```

Command:

```
docker container run -d -p 8080:8080 -v C:\Users\shibasish.das\Workspace\TestProfileFrontEnd:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT --name <****/container_name> <image name>
```

When I check the mount, I saw the following host mount address:

```
/host_mnt/c/Users/shibasish.das/Workspace/TestProfileFrontEnd
```

I tried some suggestions from the docker and github forums [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1516) and [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1560) but unsuccessful.

Comment: Is it on purpose that your are copying files to a tomcat rootdir when you build your image (Dockerfile) and you later override this same rootdir with your bind mount ? What is the content for the windows folder your are trying to bind mount ? What are you seeing in your container (i.e. `docker exec your_container_name ls -la /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT` ?

Comment: Well, it is not intentional. I want to have a container where my code runs in dev environment. Whenever, I make changes to the code, the same should get reflected in the container. I think, I am making a mistake having COPY in dockerfile and then using mount.

Comment: Right, in that case you don't need to put the code in the image.  Just mount the directory as a volume when you run the image.  As for possible issues with volume mounting in Windows, make sure you have selected that the drive should be shared in the Docker for Windows settings.  You may also need to use the "Reset Credentials" link if your password has changed since you installed Docker for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I was copying files through docker file and then mounting a volume. The files somehow were getting replaced. Solution: Use either of mounting or docker file.

I removed the copy from docker file and used mounting volumes as I was in dev mode. Later, for other non-prod environments, I am removing the mounting and using docker copy.